# Top 10 Filter Dashboard Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I am using performance point for showing reports in Sharepoint 2010 BI center. My requirement is to show top 10 items for all the hierarchy levels by default. User should not right click and select top 10 filter, instead the report should show top 10 items by default. I am not sure how should I acheive this.

**Process I have tried**:

I created a filter to show regions in the drop down and wanted to connect this to my report and based on the region selection I would like to show top 10 clients and top 10 products within that each client.

Can someone please help me with this

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Make topcount named set in the Analysis service cube and use this set as basis for the report.
You should make as many named sets as you have different hierarchies.

[See this link for more info on Microsoft developer network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx)